# GAE java - Converting app to modules - default app version vs default module

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I want to convert my app to modules (I haven't used backends before) and I have some questions regarding app module structure and how does module structure affect the way an application sets a default version?

More specifically: I now have an app (let's say id is "myapp") with one war folder (which app engine automatically marks it as the default module as I've seen in the documentation). It is deployed to a version named v2 and mysite.com points to myapp.appspot.com, which has the default version v2.myapp.appspot.com

Let's say i want to create 2 modules, one that serves client requests (that contains web static files like html, js, css etc and the needed server classes), and one for cron jobs and taks (containing server, shared classes etc). As I've seen in the docs, I will have to create an EAR structure, with war folders for each module, but what I don't understand, is how will the deplyoment affect the way my app sets a default version? Will it be the same? That is: will I choose a default version from one of the modules ? If so, which crons will run on "default version".

Will tasks that are launched indirectly by client requests will have to be managed separately? or will I have to modify the way my task are started or my code according to my new modules?

I have only read the docs, so please excuse if some of the questions are dumb, or not clear enough... Also, any other advice or links are welcome. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Each module has it's own version. If you change the version it will be reflected in the console. From there you can set the default. Any request to the module will be sent to the default version, [unless you specify otherwise](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/modules/routing).

For taskqueues it's a [bit more complex](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/taskqueue/overview-push#Java_Task_execution). If there is a version that is the same as the one that en-queues the task it will use that one. If not it will use the default one. IE version Alpha en-queues a task. It is not the default version. If there is a module with the same version it will run on that one, otherwise it will run on the default one.